# Does retain cycle for a block applies for methods the block call?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, automatic-ref-counting

Ok, we know that we may have a retain cycle if we do this

```
[someObject messageWithBlock:^{ [self doSomething]; }];
```

and that the solution is something like this

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
[someObject messageWithBlock:^{ [weakSelf doSomething]; }];
```

But what about if we do this last code but doSomething has a lot of references to self? Like:

```
- (void) doSomething {
    self.myProperty = @"abc";
    [self doOtherThing];
}
```

Will this create a retain cycle?

and what about this:

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
[someObject messageWithBlock:^{ 
   self.onError(NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"Error", MY_TABLE, nil))
}];
```

Where MY_TABLE is a `#define`?

Comment: retain cycle is created when we have more than 2 references of object. ARC decrease the retain count by on when goes out of scope. But if we have more than 1 strong references of a object, then retain cycle occurs. (i) To remove the retain cycle , Always take weak references of object specifically in case of blocks. because block create a separate copy of objects  i like this what you did:  __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
[someObject messageWithBlock:^{ [weakSelf doSomething]; }];  (ii) For function not Any issue

Comment: please make this comment an answer, so I can accept. thanks

Comment: I think function is just a type of placeholder code, so reference your `weak self` there would make no problem

Comment: THANKS, I HAVE ADDED  an Answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No retain cycle in this code:**

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
[someObject messageWithBlock:^{ [weakSelf doSomething]; }];

- (void) doSomething {
    self.myProperty = @"abc";
    [self doOtherThing];
}
```

**Explanation**

In the above code

```
[weakSelf doSomething];
```

means the receiver object (self) has now become weakSelf ie. any call to self inside **doSomething** will refer to weakSelf.
Thus reference to self inside doSomething would not create a retain cycle.

**Talking about the code below:**

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
[someObject messageWithBlock:^{ 
   self.onError(NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"Error", MY_TABLE, nil))
}];
```

as the receiver object  inside the block is **self**, and not weakSelf this would create a retain cycle.

Comment: Thanks. In the second code MY_TABLE is a define, but suppose it was an ivar defined on the class. Would it create a retain cycle?

Answer (score 1):

retain cycle is created when we have more than 2 references of object. ARC decrease the retain count by on when goes out of scope. But if we have more than 1 strong references of a object, then retain cycle occurs.

(i) To remove the retain cycle , Always take weak references of object specifically in case of blocks. because block create a separate copy of objects i like this what you did:

```
 __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self; 
[someObject messageWithBlock:^{ 
[weakSelf doSomething];
 }];
```

(ii) For function not Any issue

```
- (void) doSomething {
    self.myProperty = @"abc";
    [self doOtherThing];
}
```